# Maven deploy does not work via command line (mvn) but works using plexus-classworlds Launcher. Why is this happening?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, drools, maven-plugin

I have a Maven Drools project that has .DRL files in it.

The .DRL files happen to contain Japanese characters. The file names are also in Japanese.

When I try to execute the following command, org.kie plugin cannot generate a model because it cannot parse the characters.

`mvn -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 deploy -P deployToDistribution`

It really makes me wonder why such a simple command cannot work properly given that the encoding is already specified in the command line. I have also set the '<project.build.sourceEncoding>' in the pom.xml to UTF-8.

The error that I encounter is this:

[command line error after executing the mvn command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHo89.png)

When I use the following Plexus Classworlds Launcher, no errors occur.

`"%JAVA_HOME%bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%~dp0 "-Dmaven.home=%~dp0\.mvn\home" "-Dclassworlds.conf=%~dp0\.mvn\home\m2.conf" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "%~dp0\.mvn\home\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;%~dp0\.mvn\home\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher deploy -P deployToDistributionRepository`

Due to my boss requiring the 'mvn' command to work, I simply cannot proceed with the Plexus Classworlds solution.

Can anybody please tell me why is this happening? Is there any way I can convert the Plexus Classworlds command into a mvn command? I feel like I'm out of options.

Thanks in advance and peace out

Comment: First don't use images better use text (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/296328) furthermore I don't know if you have done that on command line or from inside an IDE? The image looks like that... Can you give more details which Maven version do you use? Which JDK version? Are you running from inside IDE ? Why do you use a non default project layout? Best would be a full working example...

Comment: I was running the command from the command line (Windows 10). At the root directory where the pom.xml is located.

Java Version is 1.8.0_282.

AdoptOpenJDK Runtime Environment build 1.8.0_282-b08.

Not running from inside IDE. Only from the command line.

Comment: Which Maven version? How do you call it? Please add more details...best would be a full working example...